# Amortized analysis of an ordered stack

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I was working through a tutorial sheet I found online and came across a question I couldn't figure out how to solve.

http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall08/Problems/amortized.pdf

An ordered stack S is a stack where the elements appear in increasing order. It supports the following operations:

Init(S): Create an empty ordered stack.

Pop(S): Delete and return the top element from the ordered stack.

Push(S, x): Insert x at top of the ordered stack and re-establish the increasing
order by repeatedly removing the element immediately below x until x is the
largest element on the stack.

Destroy(S): Delete all elements on the ordered stack.

Argue that the amortized running time of all operations is O(1). Can anyone help?

Comment: As a hint, use a potential function. Try setting the potential to be the height of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you can do is,

firstly prove that init(s), pop(S) and destroy() really actually takes O(1) time ( and they really do.)

then for the push(S, x) function that is asymtotically increasing the complexity to O(n) argue that the push() will start with O(1) time and continue to give the same complexity until unless a number smaller than the top of the stack in pushed. the probability of this happening can be calculated to support your argument.

(do comment if something is not correct)

Comment: The destroy processes every element in the stack. 

Actual cost for insert = k+1
Potential = height of tree (n)

Amortized cost = K+1 + (N-K+1) - (N) = 2

Don't know what to do this this.